# How can I create a seaborn regression plot with multiindex dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, linear-regression, seaborn

I have time series data which are multi-indexed on (Year, Month) as seen here:

```
print(df.index)
print(df)
```

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[2016, 2017], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],
           names=['Year', 'Month'])
            Value
Year Month            
2016 3       65.018150
     4       63.130035
     5       71.071254
     6       72.127967
     7       67.357795
     8       66.639228
     9       64.815232
     10      68.387698
```

I want to do very basic linear regression on these time series data. Because `pandas.DataFrame.plot` does not do any regression, I intend to use Seaborn to do my plotting.

I attempted to do this by using `lmplot`:

```
sns.lmplot(x=("Year", "Month"), y="Value", data=df, fit_reg=True)
```

but I get an error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'tuple'
```

This is particularly interesting to me because all elements in `df.index.levels[:]` are of type `numpy.int64`, all elements in `df.index.labels[:]` are of type `numpy.int8`.

Why am I receiving this error? How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following approach:

```
df['x'] = df.index.get_level_values(0) + df.index.get_level_values(1)/100
```

yields:

```
In [49]: df
Out[49]:
                Value        x
Year Month
2016 3      65.018150  2016.03
     4      63.130035  2016.04
     5      71.071254  2016.05
     6      72.127967  2016.06
     7      67.357795  2016.07
     8      66.639228  2016.08
     9      64.815232  2016.09
     10     68.387698  2016.10
```

let's prepare X-ticks labels:

```
labels = df.index.get_level_values(0).astype(str) + '-' + \
         df.index.get_level_values(1).astype(str).str.zfill(2)

sns.lmplot(x='x', y='Value', data=df, fit_reg=True)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to turn the dataframe's index into columns. Plotting DataFrames columns is then straight forward with seaborn.

As I guess the reason to use `lmplot` would be to show different regressions for different years (otherwise a `regplot` may be better suited), the `"Year"`column can be used as `hue`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn.apionly as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iterables = [[2016, 2017], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['Year', 'Month'])
df = pd.DataFrame({"values":np.random.rand(24)}, index=index)

df2 = df.reset_index()  # or, df.reset_index(inplace=True) if df is not required otherwise 

g = sns.lmplot(x="Month", y="values", data=df2, hue="Year")

plt.show()
```

[image]